# How do I load images from left to right with Lazyload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading

I want to load images in one at a time on the page from left to right and I can't figure out where i am going wrong. Following the [example here](http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/index.php?c=effects) my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2836bhwe/) project should work. I have also made sure that the console was not showing any errors. The code in the fiddle is the same as the suggested code from the documentation:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("img.lazy").lazy({
        effect: "fadeIn",
        effectTime: 1500
    });
});
```

Comment: What behavior do you get and how is that different from what you expect?

Comment: Because all of the images in the fiddle are in view, then you don't  see them loading. I don't think there's an issue, it's more how you're expecting it to work

Comment: @bitfiddler if you look at the fiddle the images just appear. They do not load in one at a time as I explained in the description.

Comment: @Stokedout How do I go about loading the images in the way I am asking?

Comment: @Skullomania do you need the lazy loading or do you only want some kind of left to right animation?

Comment: no...I was only wanting to animate the pictures from left to right. I assumed that you could use lazyload to accomplish this task.